# Calling JavaScript function from other frame present in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iFrame in my HTML page `iFrame_Example.html`

```
<iframe src="1.html" height="400" width="400"></iframe>
```

`1.html` has two `frames` in it

```
    <frameset rows="30,*" frameborder=0 border=0>
        <frame id="top_frame" name="top_frame"src="top_frame.htm"></frame>
        <frame id="main_frame" name="main_frame"src="main_frame.htm"></frame>
    </frameset>
```

Now in `top_frame.htm` I have a button

```
<input type="button" value="Hi" onClick="top.main_frame.SayHi()">
```

`SayHi()` is in `main_frame.htm`

```
function SayHi()
{
  alert("Hi");
}
```

When I run `1.html` in browser, the function `SayHi()` gets called properply. But when I run   `iFrame_Example.html` it deosn't work.

How do I call the function with onClick event ? Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Wow!  I haven't seen a `<frameset>` tag in years.

Comment: @Rocket My client loves it :(

Comment: I'm sorry.  Can't you just tell the client they're wrong? (I know you can't lol)

Comment: Client is never wrong. Period.

Comment: Tell your client that frames were part of the 90's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `frames.top_frame.SayHi()`?

**Update:** I think you may need `parent.frames.top_frame.SayHi()`

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: `frames.main_frame is undefined`